# "An item with the same key has already been added." while key is checked first

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

Well I'm completely puzzled about an error I receive from our production environment.

> mscorlib:
> An item with the same key has already been added.

with stacktrace

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>
> at Domain.MyClass.CompleteReasons(Dictionary`2 reasons)
>
> at Domain.MyClass.ctor(...)
>
> at ... (tree of calling methods)
>
> at MySite.MyPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nothing unusual about that, but if you look at that `CompleteReasons` method:

```
Private Function CompleteReasons(ByVal reasons As Dictionary(Of MyReasonsEnum, String)) As Dictionary(Of MyReasonsEnum, String)
  If reasons Is Nothing Then
    reasons = New Dictionary(Of MyReasonsEnum, String)()
  End If
  For Each reason As MyReasonsEnum In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(MyReasonsEnum))
    If Not reasons.ContainsKey(reason) Then
      reasons.Add(reason, ReasonToString(reason))
    End If
  Next
  Return reasons
End Function
```

You'll see that the only place where a dictionary item is added is within a key check.

Have only seen this in production and haven't been able to trigger the issue neither on the production systems and on my own debug environment.

Our production server is a Windows Server 2012 R2, running IIS 8.5

Anybody any ideas on how I'm able too keep this from happening or where I can find more info on the cause, because this is all intel I have.

Comment: Where is the code called from? If you called the method from two different threads, there's a race condition that could cause that error...

Comment: Indirectly from the onload of a web form. The pages main object is retrieved from the database and as part of the function that converts the data to a usable object it also fills the sub object, here depicted as MyClass. There are cases where this is done multiple times in a request (e.g. the overview page for the main object), but on this page it only happens once per request.

Comment: You may need to lock the reasons dictionary to synchronize access to the  dictionary

Comment: How do you lock a dictionary? Never had to do such a thing.

Comment: How is `reasons` declared? Is it static / shared?

Comment: The class this is all happening in isn't static. The reasons variable is a parameter passed through to this function.
The idea behind it is that a custom set of reasons can optionally be given to the constructor of the class and this function will add all missing entries in the set with the default values.

Comment: Is the reasons parameter which is being passed through static/shared?  It looks very similar to a race condition.

Comment: In regards to how to lock a dictionary, you can either do some tasty stuff with synclocks which are a right pain in the or you can use the .net 4.0 ConcurrentDictionary object - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well normally, no static objects are used in this process. The class this is all happening is just instantiated and the parameter was provided along with the constructor, after being read from the database.
I'll look into the synclock and ConcurrentDictionary and see if that helps. Error didn't occur in the last few days though.